# Prove that $f(x)=x^3 −x−1$ has at least one real root.

Tags: calculus, polynomials

How would I go about proving this?
Would I try finding a value for $x$ that will make $f(x) = 0$?

Comment: All odd polynomials have a real root. Hint:IVT

Comment: Find an $x$ at which your function is negative, and one where the function is positive. Then Intermediate Value Theorem. Note that $x=1$ and $x=2$ work, so there is a root between $1$ and $2$. (It would be quite painful to find an explicit expression for a root.)

Answer (score 3):

It's continuous, odd powered polynomial, which means it goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, which in turn means that it crosses $x$ axis somewhere in between.

Comment: How would I prove that it's continuous?

Comment: @JakePark all polynomials are continuous.

Comment: Is there a way I can prove this on paper?

Comment: Perhaps by using limits in anyway?

Comment: @JakePark, yes. Namely, you need to prove that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$, for any given polynomial $f(x)$.

Comment: @Kaster Prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}x=a$, prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}kx=ka$ for a constant $k\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}x^n=a^n$ or $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)g(x)=f(a)g(a)$ when $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous. Finally prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(f(x)+g(x))=f(a)+g(a)$ for $f$ and $g$ continuous. As a corollary polynomials are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

No, as the real root in this case is not a nice number.  Instead, you can use the fact that polynomials (such as $x^3-x-1$) are continuous to help you show that there is a root.

If you can find some $x$ such that $x^3-x-1<0$, and some $y$ such that $y^2-y-1>0$, then there must be some $z$ between $x$ and $y$ such that $z^3-z-1=0$.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wolframalpha.com](https://www4b.wolframalpha.com/input/subpodimage.jsp?podtitle=Root%20plot&cdtf=MSP17371fb5e4ieih4ci4fd00003a3i75hd45380dd2&i=x%5E3-x-1%3D0&theme=1&plottype=Default&incframe=false&inctitle=false&incinput=false&mck=&spidx=1&s=22&id=MSP17361fb5e4ieih4ci4fd000060g33b5dc27bd3g5&podidentifier=RootPlot&subtitle=&&&view=preview&zoom=s&subselection=undefined&as=null&au=null&at=null&))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Pick $x=1$ and $x=2$. $f(1)=-1$ and $f(2)= 5$.  As $f$ is continious, then it has to cut $x-axis$ somewhere between $x\in(1,2)$, that is it has at least one root.

Answer (score -2):

So, $\space$the$\space$ $f(x) = x^3 - x - 1$

Then,$\space$ $x$ $(x^2 - 1) - 1$, by pulling out an $x$.

$\rightarrow$ $x - 1$ is equal to $x = 1$

$\rightarrow$ $x^2 - 1$ is equal to $x^2 = 1$, then sqrt both sides, $x = 1$

However, If you apply the limit test of $lim_x\rightarrow_\infty$ of the $f(x) = x^3 -x -1$, then the $f(x) =\infty$ so the function is continuous.

Comment: You can also go to the this link and it will explain u how to figure out the real root of the function.[link] http://www.wolframalpha.com. Input the x^3-x-1 in the box.